# [Sitecore EXM]ERROR Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm

I'm using Sitecore 10.3 and working with EXM through "**Send Email Campaign Message**"
action. It's working fine in single environment but while deploying to distributed environment, I got the below error on logs also checked Dispatch Queue Table and find it Empty**

**[Error from Logs : ]**

```
INFO  Registered email: [email]@gmail.com 37192 15:49:20 ERROR 
Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: Execution         
Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion 
of the operation or the server is not responding. Operation 
cancelled by user. The statement has been terminated. Source: .Net 
SqlClient Data Provider    at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException 
exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStat 
eObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean 
asyncClose)    at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, 
SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, 
BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject 
stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at 
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, 
SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, 
BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject 
stateObj)    
at 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)    
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinuedOnSuccess(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)    
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
```

Comment: It looks like a database connection issue in the distributed environment, please make sure that all servers/instances in the distributed environment have access to the database.